# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replaceChild' of null

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to make this work for hours. None of the documentation or answers here have helped yet.

I'm trying to replace each item in the flippedCards array with an empty div.

Getting the parent works fine, it gives back a div element. The error is when asking for the child, it says it's null, or sometimes undefined.

There's only two items with the class of "flip".

I only want to use JS.

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="flip">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var flippedCards = document.querySelectorAll('.flip');

var replaceCards = document.createElement("div");

while (flippedCards[0] && flippedCards[1]) {
flippedCards[0].parentElement.replaceChild(replaceCards, flippedCards[0])          
flippedCards[1].parentElement.replaceChild(replaceCards, flippedCards[1]);
}
```

Comment: `flippedCards[0].parentElement` is coming as null. Please post your HTML code also.

Comment: Ok, I've added the basic HTML involved.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error message. Either the JS is under the HTML (or the JS waits for the `DOMContentLoaded` event) and it works fine (although the result is only one `<div>`, because you have only created one and `replaceCards` refers to the same one), or your JS is _above_ the HTML and it says that `flippedCards[0]` is undefined, but not `flippedCards[0].parentElement`.

Comment: console.log/dir works fine on flippedCards[0].parentElement. It returns what I'd expect. So it works up until it hit the replace bit.

Comment: @user3055938 Still can’t reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var flippedCards = document.querySelectorAll('.flip');
var replaceCards = document.createElement("div");

flippedCards[0].parentElement.replaceChild(replaceCards, flippedCards[0]);
replaceCards = document.createElement("div");       
flippedCards[1].parentElement.replaceChild(replaceCards, flippedCards[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered it then they deleted their answer. Was a two piece mistake on my part. Was wrapped in a while loop to check if those values existed in the first place. Then I didn't make two replaceCards.